# Not able to Render Images through Spotfire Webplayer

Tags: image, spotfire, renderer, spotfire-webplayer

I loaded a table which contains the URL to the pictures on a SharePoint. I set the column to "image from URL" and then updated the settings to the contain the https:\path{$}.png. When I use a mapped shared drive (rather than sharepoint) it works on the spotfire software without needing to update the settings as above. However, neither situation allow me to render the image through the web player.

I'm using version 10.3.3.

Appreciate any guidance out there.

Best Regards,

Anthony

Comment: Could this be a permission issue? Does the account running the web players node manager service have access to the SharePoint content?

Comment: Thanks Monte, do you know how I would verify that?

Comment: The node manager runs as a windows service on the web player server. The account which runs it should have access to the SharePoint location.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit unfamiliar with the backend network setup. The account which runs the node manager should have access? Is that typically an IT function or dos my local account run the node manager?

Answer (score 0):

it's because your PC has access to the server where the image is placed, but the Spotfire webserver has not.
Try to put the image in a shared network folder that can be accessed with \\the_server\the_folder\the_image.png